# Where does android get complementary colors from? @color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector

Tags: android, colors, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

My file does not have these `res/values/colors.xml`, and there is no other file with colors in res floder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#F44336</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF9800</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FFEB3B</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="black">#121212</color>
    <color name="white">#982323</color>
</resources>
```

But

```
 Inherits from: @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton:     android:android:textColor = @color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector
```

Where i can find  `@color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is defined by the default style in the library.

The `res/color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector.xml` is provided by the library.
You can find the [source here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.3.0-rc01/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/color/mtrl_text_btn_text_color_selector.xml).